# Drawing a dashed line with CGContextSetLineDash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cgcontext

I'm trying to draw a dashed line with `CGContextSetLineDash`.

Here's my code:

```
float dashPhase = 0.0;
float dashLengths[] = {30, 30};
CGContextSetLineDash(context, dashPhase, dashLengths, 20.0);
self.previousPoint2 = self.previousPoint1;
self.previousPoint1 = previous;
self.currentPoint = current;

self.mid1 = [self pointBetween:self.previousPoint1 andPoint:self.previousPoint2];
self.mid2 = [self pointBetween:self.currentPoint andPoint:self.previousPoint1];

UIBezierPath* newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[newPath moveToPoint:self.mid1];
[newPath addLineToPoint:self.mid2];
[newPath setLineWidth:self.brushSize];
```

However, if I draw slowly, they dashed lines do not appear (see top of image below) but if I draw quickly, they do appear (see bottom of image below).

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set `dashPhase = 0.`, therefore each time you start a new line, the pattern starts with a 30 unit painted segment, followed by a 30 unit unpainted segment. If the line segments are short, the entire line will be painted.

So either you use a single path, where you only append line segments, or you compute for each new subpath the `dashPhase` where to start the pattern.

(Shouldn't the last parameter of `CGContextSetLineDash` be the length of the `dashLengths[]`, i.e. `2` ?)

**UPDATE:** As we figured out in the discussion, the solution to the problem was indeed to add line segments to the last bezier path as long as the user draws the same curve:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // ...
    // Compute nextPoint to draw ...
    UIBezierPath *lastPath = [self.paths lastObject]; 
    [lastPath addLineToPoint:self.nextPoint];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I changed a few bits based on your comments, but still, when I draw slowly the dashed lines just all merge together

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: What means "drawing slowly" exactly? Can you show the updated code?

Comment: Most likely "drawing slowly" means that the points captured a visually close to each other causing the issue you described. I think the reasonable approach would be to append segments to the path, redrawing previous parts if needed to make sure the dashes are drawn properly.

Comment: well drawing across 30 pixels every second or so - here's my updated code: http://pastie.org/5099406

Comment: @HenriNormak how would I go about doing that? Could you post a small example as an answer please? :-)

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: You still use a fixed `dashPhase`, that cannot work with separate path segments, because each segment starts with a fresh pattern. As Henri and I have suggested, you should use a single path where you append line segments.

Comment: I don't understand though - how can I do that?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: The idea is that you use a single bezier path, call `moveToPoint` only once, and then `addLineToPoint` for each line segment, and finally `stroke` the path.

Comment: could you post an example? I'm a bit lost - I thought that's what I'm already doing?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101: You create a new bezier path `newPath` for each line segment. Perhaps you can post your complete drawing function, that would make it easier to suggest improvements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18423/discussion-between-martin-r-and-d3v3l0p3r101)