# Dashed lines with CGContextStrokePath

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cgcontext

I am developing an app where the user should be able to draw lines with the finger. The user can enable dashed lines, but I am having a strange problem when trying to do so.  If the user drags the finger slowly a solid line appears, but when doing it fast the dashes appears. I would like the dashes to appear no matter what when enabled. The problem is shown on the gif below:
[image: Dashes do not appear when dragging slowly]

I am collecting the touch points with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
-(void)dragGestureCaptured:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSValue* touchPoint = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[gesture locationInView:self.drawingView]];

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        [self initializePreviousPointValues:[touchPoint CGPointValue]];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        EBLog(@"Dragging ends..");
        return;
    }

    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = currentPoint;
    currentPoint = [touchPoint CGPointValue];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    [self.drawingView addDrawColor:self.currentDrawColor];
    [self.drawingView.controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:previousPoint1]];
    [self.drawingView.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:mid2]];
    [self.drawingView.movePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:mid1]];

    [self.drawingView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The `drawingView` uses the `controlsPoints`, `points` and `movePoints` to draw the lines:

```
- (void)drawLinesInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{    
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.points count]; i++)
    {
        CGPoint movePoint = [[self.movePoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint controlPoint = [[self.controlPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint point = [[self.points objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, movePoint.x, movePoint.y);
        CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, controlPoint.x, controlPoint.y, point.x, point.y);

        NSNumber* colorHash = [self.colorHashes objectAtIndex:i];
        UIColor* col = [self.colorsForHashValue objectForKey:colorHash];

        CGFloat red = 0.0f, blue = 0.0f, green = 0.0f, alpha = 1.0f;

        [col getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];

        if (alpha == 0.0f)
        {
            penWidth = 15.0f;
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
        }
        else
        {
            penWidth = 5.0f;
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, alpha);
        }

        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, penWidth);
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false);

        if (self.drawDashedLines)
        {
            CGFloat dashLengths[] = {10.0f, 10.0f};
            CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0.0f, dashLengths, 2);
        }

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

`drawLinesInContext:` is invoked in `drawRect:`.

What am I doing wrong, since the dashes don't appear when dragging slowly?

I have already seen the [Drawing a dashed line with CGContextSetLineDash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016816/drawing-a-dashed-line-with-cgcontextsetlinedash) and tried the `CGPathAddLineToPoint` to see if it makes a difference, but it didn't. I was experiencing the exact same problem.

Comment: It seems to me that this is the same issue as this one: [Drawing a dashed line with CGContextSetLineDash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016816/drawing-a-dashed-line-with-cgcontextsetlinedash).

Comment: Yes, but that is about `UIBezierPath`, which I am not using :-)

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but the problems seems to be the same: You draw N separate curves, and each curve starts a new dash. If the finger is moved slowly, you have lots of very short paths, and therefore no dash is seen. - You have to build and draw a single path connecting *all* points. Can you show what you tried with CGPathAddLineToPoint ?

Comment: It makes sense, but how to I access the current path when I am using `CGContextStrokePath`? I have tried replacing `CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint` with `CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y)`, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you draw separate paths between each subsequent points, and
each path starts with a new dash pattern. If the finger is moved slowly, you draw
lots of very short path. It the path is shorter than 10 points (the first
dash length which is *drawn*) then no dash pattern is seen at all.

The following pseudo-code hopefully shows the idea how to solve this. Instead of

```
for i = 1 ... N {
    move to point[i-1] 
    curve to point[i]
    set line dash
    stroke path
}
```

it should be

```
move to point[0]
for i = 1 ... N {
    curve to point[i]
}
set line dash
stroke path
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I figured out a few moments ago. I ended up only moving the point when the user had lifted the finger and started to draw again. The last line I ended with `CGContextStrokePath` to be able to make different colors in the same collection of points. Thanks a lot!