# Dotted line in drawing not works when I draw line slowly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, drawing

I am developing drawing feature in ios, I have 3 type of lines

- PLANE
- DASHED
- DOTTED

The problem is with **DOTTED lines**, when I draw quickly it draws fine, but when I draw it slowly it draws solid line

Bellow is the code snippet, please guide me where is the problem.

```
- (void)drawingLayerMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    //MOVE START
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        dw_mouseSwiped = NO;
        dw_lastPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tempDrawImage.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tempDrawImage.frame.size.width, self.tempDrawImage.frame.size.height)];

    }
    //MOVING
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        dw_mouseSwiped = YES;
        CGPoint currentPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];
        CGContextRef dw_context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        if( [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DOTTED_LINE] ) {
            CGContextSetLineCap(dw_context, kCGLineCapRound);
        }
        else if( [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DASHED_LINE] ) {
            CGContextSetLineCap(dw_context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        }
        else if( [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_PLANE_LINE]  ) {
            CGContextSetLineCap(dw_context, kCGLineCapRound);
        }

        // ADD FEW SPACES B/W DOTS OF LINE
        if( [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DASHED_LINE] || [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DOTTED_LINE] ) {
            CGFloat dw_dash[] = {2,dw_brush*3,dw_brush*2,dw_brush};
            CGContextSetLineDash(dw_context, 1, dw_dash, 4);
        }

        //BRUSH WIDTH ( we have devided it on 3 )
        CGContextSetLineWidth(dw_context, (dw_brush/3));

        if( [dw_drawingLayerMode isEqualToString:DRAWING_LAYER_MODE_ERASER] ){
            //BRUSH CLEAR COLOR
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( dw_context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor );
            //CLEAR DRAWING
            CGContextSetBlendMode(dw_context, kCGBlendModeClear);
        } else{
            // BRUSH RGB COLOR
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(dw_context, dw_red, dw_green, dw_blue, dw_opacity);
            //NORMAL DRAWING
            CGContextSetBlendMode(dw_context,kCGBlendModeNormal);
        }

        CGContextMoveToPoint(dw_context, dw_lastPoint.x, dw_lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(dw_context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(dw_context);

        //SAVE CURRENT MOVE INFO IN TEMP IMG
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        //SAVE CURRENT MOVE POINT AS dw_lastPoint
        dw_lastPoint = currentPoint;

    }
    //MOVE END
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

My problem is simmiler like this question, but didn't found solution in it:
[Drawing a dashed line with CGContextSetLineDash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016816/drawing-a-dashed-line-with-cgcontextsetline)[image]

Comment: The approach of drawing the path to an image for each change won't work if you want to dash the line. You will have to keep adding to the same mutable path and redraw it.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist it would be great if you can help me in writing the code, I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem,
I have updated the code of move with my custom logic,

```
//MOVING
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        dw_mouseSwiped = YES;
        CGPoint currentPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.tempDrawImage];
        BOOL dw_addThisPointInLine  =   YES;


        if( ([dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DASHED_LINE] || [dw_brushType  isEqual: DRAWING_DOTTED_LINE]) && !([dw_drawingLayerMode isEqualToString:DRAWING_LAYER_MODE_ERASER]) ) {

            CGFloat dw_points_distance  = 0.0;
            dw_points_distance = [self distanceBtwPoints:currentPoint p2:dw_lastPoint];

            if( dw_points_distance < dw_brush)
            dw_addThisPointInLine  =   NO;

            if( !(dw_addThisPointInLine) ) {
                if( dw_points_distance > 30 && dw_brush < 50)
                dw_addThisPointInLine  =   YES;
                else if( dw_points_distance > 40 && dw_brush < 80)
                dw_addThisPointInLine  =   YES;
                else if( dw_points_distance > 50 && dw_brush < 100)
                dw_addThisPointInLine  =   YES;
            }
        }

        if( dw_addThisPointInLine ) {
             //shif the code of move inside this condition.
        }


}//move code end
```